# How compare int[] elements in arraylist?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, compare

```
public company(String a, int[] b)
```

I created a class, `company`.

```
ArrayList<company> c1;
int temp;
for(company c:c1) {
    if (temp > c.getb()) {
        temp = c.getb();
    }
```

There is a list of companies, and a company has a number of integers stored in it as an `int[]`.

I am trying to compare and get the largest value from `int[] b`.

But my code is showing an error since `c.getb()` is `int[]` array so can't be compared by `<` or `>`

So, I am not sure how to compare `int[]` values in the `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 4):

> I am trying to compare and get the largest value from int[] b.

Your code has several issues:

```java
ArrayList<company> c1 = ...
int temp;
for(company c : c1) {
    if (temp > c.getb()) {
        temp = c.getb();
    }
}
```

First, you need to initialize `temp` to a value, which value ? `Integer.MIN_VALUE;`, because you are trying to get the **largest** value. Moreover, this:

```java
for(company c : c1) {
    if (temp > c.getb()) {
        temp = c.getb();
    }
}
```

is not getting the largest it is getting the **smallest**. So what you actually want to do is the following:

```java
List<company> c1 = ....
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(company c : c1) {
    int temp = Arrays.stream(c.getb()).max().getAsInt();
    max = Math.max(temp, max);
}
```

If you don't want to use the `Arrays.stream` you can create the function yourself:

```java
public static int maxArray(int [] array){
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for(int e :  array) {
        max = Math.max(e, max);
    }
    return max;
}
```

Which as you can see it is very similar to what you are trying to do in the first place.

With Java streams you can do it as follows:

```
ArrayList<company> c1 = ...
int max = c1.stream()
            .map(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getb()).max().getAsInt())
            .max(Comparator.naturalOrder())
            .orElse(Integer.MIN_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the max value of an array with primitives with native java methods:

`Collections.max(Arrays.asList(array));`

To save performance we are going to save the list. Also you can't compare temp to something because you didn't initialize temp.

If you want to get bigger numbers you would want to do `temp < max` instead of `temp > max` so then every iteration you would check if the company element's b array has a greater number than its predecessor.

```
List<company> c1 = ....
int temp = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
for(company c:c1) {
    int max = Collections.max(Arrays.asList(c.getb()));
    if (temp < max) {
        temp = max;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
ArrayList<company> c1 = new ArrayList<>();
// ....
int temp = c1.stream()
    .flatMapToInt(c -> Arrays.stream(c.getB()))
    .max().getAsInt();
```

When the list is empty, there is no maximum value, so `NoSuchElementException` is thrown.

Comment: Instead of using `.getAsInt()`, would suggest to use `.orElse(0)` for the case that the stream is empty

Comment: @Lino the only issue with that is that zero might actually be a valid max

Comment: @dreamcrash agreed, it really depends on the input data, so `Integer.MIN_VALUE` might be more suited

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // The arraylist of company
        ArrayList<Company> c1 = new ArrayList<>();
        
        // First set of data creating the int[] for Apple company and inserting in c1 List
        int[] i = { 9, 4, 7, 5, 10, 8 };
        c1.add(new Company("Apple", i));
        
        // Second set of data creating the int[] for Samsung company and inserting in c1 List
        i = new int[] { 0, 2, -3, 4, 5 };
        c1.add(new Company("Samsung", i));

        // The arraylist has now 2 companies
        
        
        // First we store the largest from the array of the first company in temp
        int temp = Runner.findLargestFromArray(c1.get(0).getB());
        
        // We iterate the arraylist of the companies
        for (Company c : c1) {
            // For each company we find the largest of int[] B 
            int l = Runner.findLargestFromArray(c.getB());
            
            // If temp is less than the largest it will be updated
            if (temp < l) {
                temp = l;
            }

        }
        // the largest of arrays of both the companies is stored here i.e 10
        System.out.println(temp);
    }

    // Method which takes array as an input and returns the highest number stored in it
    public static int findLargestFromArray(int[] arr) {

        int largest = arr[0];
        int index = 1;
        while (index < arr.length) {
            // check if largest is smaller than element
            if (largest < arr[index]) {
                // update largest
                largest = arr[index];
            }
            index++;
        }
        return largest;
    }

}
```

Main driver code

```
package mpackage;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class Company {
    String a;
    int[] b;
    
    
    public Company() {
    }


    public Company(String a, int[] b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }


    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }


    public void setA(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }


    public int[] getB() {
        return b;
    }


    public void setB(int[] b) {
        this.b = b;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Company [a=" + a + ", b=" + Arrays.toString(b) + "]";
    }

    
}
```

Company Class